# Asp.net 5 DNX and DNU not working in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, dnvm

I have successfully installed the dnvm using commands given here `https://github.com/aspnet/home`.

Now I am trying `dnvm upgrade` but somehow it is not working for me. I get the latest version from nuget and I can see it being created to my `.dnx\runtimes` folder. See following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dnvm upgrade
Determining latest version
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4 from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Installing to C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4
Adding C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4\bin to user PATH

Updating alias 'default' to 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4'

C:\Users\Administrator>dnu

C:\Users\Administrator>

C:\Users\Administrator>dnx

C:\Users\Administrator>

C:\Users\Administrator>dnvm list

Active Version     Runtime Architecture Location                     Alias
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------                     -----
  *    1.0.0-beta4 clr     x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes default
```

`dnvm upgrade` works ok? but nothing happens when I type `dnu`, `dnx`,`dnu restore` commands. What am I missing ?I am doing it in Windows Server 2008 R2. .Net framework 4.5.2 installed.

**Update**

I just tried to get latest unstable runtime. When using `beta6-12085` the `dnu` command returns an error: `dnx.win32.dll could not be loaded. Last error: 87`

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dnvm upgrade -u
Determining latest version
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12085 from https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2
Installing to C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12085
Adding C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12085\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Users\Administrator\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12085\bin to user PATH
Updating alias 'default' to 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12085'

C:\Users\Administrator>dnu
dnx.win32.dll could not be loaded. Last error: 87
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a new install of Windows Server 2008. Installing all the updates fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, dnx compiled on windows 8 hence corresponding "minwin" version binding.
https://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/windows-7-kernel-api-refactoring . I got "error 87" on win7 too.